# Maximum waittime in call file

Tags: asterisk

I create a callfile as below:

```
channel: SIP/To_Avaya_PEER/20022
callerid: 1788888888
waittime: 300
context: from-primas
extension: 100
priority: 1
account: primas
archive: no
alwaysdelete: yes
```

I want to wait for answer longer than 3 minutes or forever. I want to keep the call in queue without using MaxRetries. How can i do? I set waittime longer but it doesnot work.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can dial via Local channel to dialplan, ANSWER call after that dial using Dial command.

Or patch asterisk source code

Comment: Thanks arheops, but Dial in Local channel is not answered, it is still the same problem.

Comment: You should answer and test. If still same, probably hangup from other side.